# iOS app distributed using TestFlight, including Crashlytics. No symbols

Tags: xcode, stack-trace, crashlytics, testflight

I've got an app which includes Crashlytics, but which I've distributed using TestFlight.

Since I've distributed the app through TestFlight, the Fabric app doesn't see the build as 'Active', and doesn't seem to track crashes.

When viewing crashes through Xcode, the code that crashes in my app isn't symbolicated, while everything else is:

[image: Missing symbols]

This isn't ideal; is there some way of getting the Fabric app to track TestFlight distributed builds?

And is this expected behaviour? That TestFlight / Xcode can't fully symbolicate crashes when we use Crashlytics?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I can get symbolicated stack traces from Crashlytics by downloading the dSYM files from TestFlight and uploading them to Crashlytics (this build used Bitcode).

Hopefully this helps somebody who runs into the same situation. I'd still be interested in hearing if use of Crashlytics is expected to break TestFlight crash reporting.